# TortoiseSVN switch Branches

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have used svn for a while but recently a couple teams were added to the project. One of the teams made a new branch and has asked me to check some of their changes. I went to the directory, right click, svn->switch and chose the new branch. I went in and tried to echo something to the page I was on to see if I was working in the new branch and I wasn't. This is a little beyond what I do but with the project getting so big I need to learn this.

Based on that, my question..is there something more to this that I am not doing? After switching the working copy to this new branch how do I work on it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The difference between checkout and switch might be adding to the confusion. I think that in your case it would be simpler to just check out the branch to a different folder since you're just doing review and it may be the most straightforward way to proceed regardless.

See this section [from the Tortoise docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html):

**To Checkout or to Switch...**

> ...that is (not really) the question. While a checkout downloads
>   everything from the desired branch in the repository to your working
>   directory, TortoiseSVN → Switch... only transfers the changed data to
>   your working copy. Good for the network load, good for your patience.
>   :-)
>
> To be able to work with your freshly generated branch or tag you have
>   several ways to handle it. You can:
>
> TortoiseSVN → Checkout to make a fresh checkout in an empty folder.
>   You can check out to any location on your local disk and you can
>   create as many working copies from your repository as you like.
>
> Switch your current working copy to the newly created copy in the
>   repository. Again select the top level folder of your project and use
>   TortoiseSVN → Switch... from the context menu.
>
> In the next dialog enter the URL of the branch you just created.
>   Select the Head Revision radio button and click on OK. Your working
>   copy is switched to the new branch/tag.
>
> Switch works just like Update in that it never discards your local
>   changes. Any changes you have made to your working copy which have not
>   yet been committed will be merged when you do the Switch. If you do
>   not want this to happen then you must either commit the changes before
>   switching, or revert your working copy to an already-committed
>   revision (typically HEAD).
>
> If you want to work on trunk and branch, but don't want the expense of
>   a fresh checkout, you can use Windows Explorer to make a copy of your
>   trunk checkout in another folder, then TortoiseSVN → Switch... that
>   copy to your new branch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Thats what I had read. Basically I have been working on ( for this conversation lets call it dir_a), the other team put a complete working copy of the current site into a new directory, lets call it dir_b. After they made changes, I went in to the top level folder and did a switch from dir_a to dir_b as my working copy. Now based on this does that mean that my current working copy now in fact has all the new functionality of this new branch?

Comment: As I understand it, not until you pull the changes. In any case, unless you have serious bandwidth issues, I would stay away from the switching step and just check out branches directly.

Comment: @PaulSasik Do you happen to know where I could find an updated link for that information?

Answer (score 5):

In the regular "Properties" dialogue (right click on Windows explorer) you have a "Subversion" tab that will tell you what URL the file or directory points to. Use that to verify that you actually switched to the correct branch.

It's also worth nothing that any non-committed local changes will still be in your working copy.

Answer (score 4):

**There might be a misconception** about **`svn switch`** :

At first I thought that the existence of a switch command would imply that there were a "current" or a "selected" working copy for the proper functioning of SVN. Like I'm currently working on trunk, then I'm working on a branch B, hence "switching" from a working copy to another. The truth is : **there is no such thing as a current working copy** ! There are just many local working copies : one for the trunk, one for a branch another for a tag and so on. But none would be  "implicitly selected".

As Paul Sasik quotes : `switch` would allow, for instance, to have only one working copy of say, the trunk, and then, merging that local working copy with a targeted branch or tag from the remote repository. `switch` only sync differences between local and remote, hence avoiding to do a whole check out of a solution. Past exectution of command, every further commits on the working copy will occur on the distant repository folder which's been switched to, which's been targeted. No matter what the initial check out was for that local folder.